# ARM disassembly and unlocking aboot.mbn

Tags: assembly, arm, bootloader

I'm brand new on this forum and in programming, so I was hoping to get a closure on how Arm binaries work and can they be disassembled and reassembled? I'm specifically interested in changing a Samsung tablet's aboot.mbn.

I installed IDA disassembler and it succesfully detected ARM and transformed it into something that makes sense. Now, the question is: what is the chance of unrecoverable failure if I make a mistake and flash a badly compiled/edited aboot? As far as I know, Odin 3 flash tool (for Samsung upgrade) has some type of image check which I suppose would detect some bigger errors like bad compiling or similar...

Anyways, I want to try to disable all types of flashing restrictions for this one (OEM unlock, Qualcomm Secure Boot, MDM) and else.

I looked up the text value for the message which would appear when I try to flash it and I found it with DCD executable (if that's how it's called, sorry for poor terminology, I'm a noob for coding). I followed the memory addresses throughout the code with diagram, and if I figured well, it pulls some secure info from some other place in memory (another partition, I think it's persist or something like that people say). Now I think I could maybe simply redirect it to not load those values, or to bind them to zero.

I feel like this is much more complicated from what it seems looking at these silly diagrams, so if someone has some experiance with ARM Android devices, that would be great. If there is interest in this topic, I can provide original file, device specs and disassembly code. I started a thread on XDA, but it got quite lonely, I guess not many assembly coders there huh https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3583942